# Travis Docker Image missing Python 3.5

Tags: python, docker, travis-ci

I was following the instructions in [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Running-a-Container-Based-Docker-Image-Locally) when trying to setup travis environment locally to track down a test failure occurring only in Travis. I downloaded the `travis-python` docker image and ran it.

The travis log shows that it runs
`source ~/virtualenv/python3.5/bin/activate` to activate python3.5. However this was not found from the provided docker image. It had all the python versions up to 3.4.2. but 3.5 was missing.

I couldn't find any instructions from the log where they would have setup `python3.5` under the `virtualenv` folder and have been trying to figure out how to do that. Does someone know how these are set up so that I could reproduce locally the environment used by Travis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in the same situation - At the moment, upstream travis installs 3.5 and 3.6 via some install-on-demand magic which their published Docker images don't seem to support :( So this isn't an answer, but a workaround which is good enough for me and might be good enough for you - installing the 3.5 venv by hand:

```
FROM quay.io/travisci/travis-python

ARG PYTHON=3.5.2

RUN \
    mkdir /home/travis/python && \
    cd /home/travis/python && \
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON}/Python-${PYTHON}.tar.xz && \
    tar xf Python-${PYTHON}.tar.xz && \
    rm Python-${PYTHON}.tar.xz
RUN \
    cd /home/travis/python/Python-${PYTHON} && \
    ./configure --prefix=/opt/python/${PYTHON}/ && \
    make && \
    make install
USER travis
RUN \
    /opt/python/${PYTHON}/bin/pyvenv /home/travis/virtualenv/python${PYTHON} && \
    ln -s /home/travis/virtualenv/python${PYTHON} /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5 && \
    /home/travis/virtualenv/python${PYTHON}/bin/pip install numpy
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this tomorrow and will accept the answer if I can reproduce the error with this!

Comment: Sorry for being dense, very new to docker/TravisCI - where would I run your code to install a python3.5 venv? That doesn't quite look like `.travis.yml`, and I'm not really sure where to go from there. Is it a Docker script or something?

Comment: This is a docker script which takes the Travis image, adds python3.5 on top of it, and outputs a new image. If you built a new image with this (`docker build -t travis-python-3.5 .` IIRC) then you can use this new image as a drop-in replacement wherever you're currently using the original Travis image.